# Отображение разделов в меню и каталоге битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть задача скрыть отображения товаров в каталоге если нет галочки в пользовательском поле.

Написан скрипт:

```
$arSelect = Array(
            "ID",
            "SECTION_PAGE_URL"
        );
$arFilter = Array(
            "IBLOCK_ID"            => 34,
            "!UF_SHOW_HEAD_MENU"=> 0,
            "ACTIVE"               => "Y"
        );
$res      = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, $arSelect);
$arTemp   = array();
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
    {
        $arFields                              = $ob->GetFields();
        $arTemp[$arFields["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]] = $arFields;
    }
unset($res);
$arTempResult = array();
foreach ($arResult as &$arMenuItem)
    {
        if ($arTemp[$arMenuItem['LINK']])
        {
            $arTempResult[] = $arMenuItem;
        }
    }
    $arResult = $arTempResult;
    unset($arTemp);
    unset($arTempResult);
```

но куда бы я его не вставлял он не функционирует, куда копать ?

Сам шаблон компонента

```
<?if( !defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true ) die();?><?
$this->setFrameMode(true);
if($_arResult = CPriority::CheckSmartFilterSEF($arParams, $component)){
    $arResult = $_arResult;
    include  __DIR__.'/section.php';
    return;
}

global $arTheme;
global $arFilter;

$arSelect = Array(
            "ID",
            "SECTION_PAGE_URL"
        );
$arFilter = Array(
            "IBLOCK_ID"            => 34,
            "PROPERTY" => Array("!UF_SHOW_HEAD_MENU"=> 0),
            "ACTIVE"               => "Y"
        );

$bOrderViewBasket = (trim($arTheme['ORDER_VIEW']['VALUE']) === 'Y');


$sectionTemplate = $sViewElementsTemplate = ($arFilter["PROPERTY"] && $arParams["SECTIONS_TYPE_VIEW"] == "FROM_MODULE" ? $arTheme['SECTIONS_TYPE_VIEW']['VALUE'] : $arParams["SECTIONS_TYPE_VIEW"]);
?>
<div class="maxwidth-theme">
    <?if($sViewElementsTemplate == 'sections_3' || $sViewElementsTemplate == 'sections_6'):?>
        <div class="row">
            <?if($arTheme["SIDE_MENU"]["VALUE"] == "RIGHT"):?>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-md">
                <?CPriority::get_banners_position('CONTENT_TOP');?>
            <?elseif($arTheme["SIDE_MENU"]["VALUE"] == "LEFT"):?>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm left-menu-md">
                    <?CPriority::ShowPageType('left_block')?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-md">
                <?CPriority::get_banners_position('CONTENT_TOP');?>
            <?endif;?>
    <?else:?>
        <?CPriority::get_banners_position('CONTENT_TOP');?>
    <?endif;?>

                <?
                // get section items count and subsections
                $arItemFilter = CPriority::GetCurrentSectionElementFilter($arResult["VARIABLES"], $arParams, false);
                $arSubSectionFilter = CPriority::GetCurrentSectionSubSectionFilter($arResult["VARIABLES"], $arParams, false);
                $itemsCnt = CCache::CIBlockElement_GetList(array("CACHE" => array("TAG" => CCache::GetIBlockCacheTag($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"]))), $arItemFilter, array());
                $arSubSections = CCache::CIBlockSection_GetList(array("CACHE" => array("TAG" => CCache::GetIBlockCacheTag($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"]), "MULTI" => "Y")), $arSubSectionFilter, false, array("ID"));

                // rss
                if($arParams['USE_RSS'] !== 'N'){
                    CPriority::ShowRSSIcon($arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['rss']);
                }
                ?>
                <?if(!$itemsCnt && !$arSubSections):?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning"><?=GetMessage("SECTION_EMPTY")?></div>
                <?else:?>
                    <?CPriority::CheckComponentTemplatePageBlocksParams($arParams, __DIR__);?>
                    <?if($arSubSections):?>
                        <?// sections?>
                        <?@include_once('page_blocks/'.$sViewElementsTemplate.'.php');?>
                    <?endif;?>                  
                    <?if($itemsCnt):?>
                        <?// section elements?>
                        <?if($arSubSections):?>
                            <div class="element_with_sections">
                        <?endif;?>
                        <?@include_once('page_blocks/'.$arParams["SECTION_ELEMENTS_TYPE_VIEW"].'.php');?>
                        <?if($arSubSections):?>
                            </div>
                        <?endif;?>

                    <?endif;?>
                <?endif;?>
    <?if($sectionTemplate == 'sections_3' || $sectionTemplate == 'sections_6'):?>
            <?if($arTheme["SIDE_MENU"]["VALUE"] == "LEFT"):?>
                <?CPriority::get_banners_position('CONTENT_BOTTOM');?>
                </div><?// class=col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 content-md?>
            <?elseif($arTheme["SIDE_MENU"]["VALUE"] == "RIGHT"):?>
                <?CPriority::get_banners_position('CONTENT_BOTTOM');?>
                </div><?// class=col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 content-md?>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm right-menu-md">
                    <?CPriority::ShowPageType('left_block')?>
                </div>
            <?endif;?>
        </div>
    <?else:?>
        <?CPriority::get_banners_position('CONTENT_BOTTOM');?>
    <?endif;?>
    <?// intro text?>
<br><div class="text_before_items">
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:main.include", 
    ".default", 
    array(
        "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "page",
        "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc",
        "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "standard.php",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "AREA_FILE_RECURSIVE" => "Y"
    ),
    false
);?>
                </div>
</div>
```

Очень прошу, помогите, подскажите куда его вставить

Answer (score 0):

Фильтрация по пользовательским полям делается так:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/getlist.php

```
$arFilter = Array(
            "IBLOCK_ID"            => 34,
            "PROPERTY" => Array("!UF_SHOW_HEAD_MENU"=> 0),
            "ACTIVE"               => "Y"
        );
```

Если меню прописано в файле .type.menu.php, то первый скрипт нужно вставить в .type.menu.php.ext. Разумеется, нужно разрешить расширения для меню.

```
// подключение модуля «iblock» для работы с инфоблоками
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');

$arSelect = Array(
            "ID",
            "SECTION_PAGE_URL"
        );
$arFilter = Array(
            "IBLOCK_ID" => 34,
            "PROPERTY"  => Array("!UF_SHOW_HEAD_MENU"=> 0),
            "ACTIVE"    => "Y"
        );
$res      = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, $arSelect);
$arTemp   = array();
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
    {
        $arFields                              = $ob->GetFields();
        $arTemp[$arFields["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]] = $arFields;
    }
unset($res);
foreach ($aMenuLinks as $key => $arMenuItem) // не $arResult, a $aMenuLinks
    {
        if (!isset($arTemp[$arMenuItem[1]]) // $arMenuItem['LINK'] - такого нет
        {
            unset($aMenuLinks[$key]);
        }
    }
return $aMenuLinks;
```

Как вариант, можно было бы сделать свою версию компонента bitrix:menu.sections, добавив в него нужные фильтры. Но это для опытных разработчиков.

Comment: Либо я тупой, либо я не туда код вставляю =( ничего не получается (